# Using less with fluid (vhs)

Tags: typo3, fluid

I'm trying to include a less file in my layout with a vhs vewhelper.

```
<v:asset.style path="EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Less/style.less" />
```

The problem is, it is included without being processed.
I've tried every less extension I could find, but all of them using typoscript to inclue de less or they add it automaticly. In both cases the compiled less is included in the template before my vhs css. That means that my reset css is included after my styles.

Adding all my css by typoscript will probably fix the problem, but there has to be a solution using viewhelpers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you want to compile your *.less files on a server by using a watcher and reference compiled files then (e.g. `EXT:my_ext/Resources/Public/Css/style.css`)?

Comment: Ok, I made a workaround and removed all my css from the template and included a single less file wich includes all mx css/less.